# Rails 6: Can't get select helper's HTML options to work properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem where I've tried to look up the select form helper in Rails 6 and implement it accordingly.  I've tried as many different ways of phrasing it as I can, but my html_options are still not firing.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :assignment_type %>
    <%= f.select(:assignment_type, options_for_select(Assignment.options, params[:type]), {},  {id: 'assign_type'})%>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#assign_type').change(function () {alert("Yayyy!!!")});
</script>
```

I don't think the problem lies within the Javascript portion, because when I change id: 'assign_type' to class: 'hidden' (which I have), it doesn't hide the element.  So I think the problem lies within the form select helper.  Let me know if I need to attach any more code.

Comment: Start by looking at the rendered HTML and add it to the question. You're also not ensuring that your js runs when the document is ready or when turbolinks replaces the page. You can just change this into a idempotent delegated handler with `$(document).on('change', '#assign_type', callback)`. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you should be able to see this in the DOM using Chrome or Firefox developer tools.

Try the following to create your select:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:assignment_type, Assignment.options, :second, :first, {}, {id: 'assign_type'}) %>
```

that should work.